# How to find where is the composer.phar file

Tags: composer-php

I manage a Drupal site with Composer and Drush. I just did an composer update of Drupal
which went perfectly well. After I wanted to update Composer itself. The only composer.phar I can find in cPanel is located in /bin.
So I did : php bin/composer.phar self-update, it went fine.

BUT it seems there is 2 versions of composer because I still got version 2.0.6
when I run composer --version. Can't find where is located this composer.phar that is running composer update.

root folder [~]# php bin/composer.phar --version
Composer version 2.1.6 2021-08-19 17:11:08
root folder [~]# composer --version
Composer version 2.0.6 2020-11-07 11:21:17

I tried
find $HOME -name "composer.phar" -print
and got only one result /bin/composer.phar
Maybe there is a version number file somewhere that is not updates properly, or cache ?

Comment: Isn't it pretty obvious that calling composer using `bin/composer.phar` is different than just using `composer`?

Answer (score 3):

There might be multiple. To find the current one being used in your $PATH, use

```
which composer
```